# Backup link between gmail, facebook, twitter contacts

Tags: contacts, backup

I have contacts from my GMail, Facebook and Twitter account. In my GMail accounts, I've saved my contacts with their first names or nicknames, so I end up having to manually link most of my Facebook & Twitter contacts with my GMail contacts. If I do a factory reset I have to repeat this process all over again. Is there a way I can backup/maintain the link between my contacts so that, after a factory reset, I can simply restore the links between contacts?

Answer (score 1):

I believe backing up the data for the Contacts Storage and restoring it should restore linked-up contacts.  You can do this with an app such as Titanium Backup (requires root).

Comment: Will gmail/facebook syncing work perfectly after restoring the contacts storage using Titanium Backup?

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it.

Comment: OK, that's unfortunate.  I wonder how the heck the linkage is stored ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work.

If you look at your contacts in GMail you'll see an extra piece of data that stores the link information.  At least mine have that for my HTC Desire.

This is what I see.

```
<HTCData><Facebook>id:123456789/friendof:123456789</Facebook></HTCData>
```

This means the sync data isn't stored on your phone at all, just as part of the contact info in Google.

Comment: That looks like it's HTC Sense doing the linking there, not the built-in Android Contacts app. I don't see anything like that on my GMail contacts and mine are linked using the standard Android linking.

Comment: My Nexus One with CyanogenMod 7 RC2 does not produce any such extra data, tough it should really be a built in feature of Android.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried, but [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=876190) seems to be the solution:

> If you use Titanium Backup, after you've re-synced your gmail/Facebook/etc. contacts, restore the "[CONTACTS/CALLS] Contacts Storage", reboot and done.
>   This of course assumes you also back this same setting up prior to wiping/loading a new ROM

Comment: It doesn't work either.